# Trigger formControl.bur event, from a typescript function

Tags: angular

I have a very simple angular reactive form having an Input angular material. I just want to

1- Set value of this control -- This is Done

2- trigger its blur event from after setting the value, using typescript. So that some other method can be called.

I am not able to do Point-2. Please help.

Comment: Think about if really you need trigger the blur event. Generally you can call to the function you executed when defined the (blur) directly

Answer (score 1):

***.component.html**

```html
<input id="name" type="text" [formControl]="name" (blur)="onBlur($event)">
```

***.components.ts**

```
onBlur(event: Event){
  console.log(event)
}
```